# How to name a log file based on date and time? how to print all exception and how to make directory in java?

Tags: java, logging

I have a situation in which i have to make a different directory to put my logs.
 i tried

```
File file = new File("c:\\className").mkdir();   But got the error incompatible type,
Found:boolean Required java.io.File, although i have imported java.io.File.
```

For the log file name i want to use something that make difference in log file name so that i can see all logs for several attempts to rub the application? how to achieve that... Please guide me to minimal code that make it...

And in a try statement i did so many thing like

```
try{
        File file=new File("C:\\className").mkdir();
        fh = new FileHandler("C:\\className\\className.log");   
            logger.addHandler(fh); 
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
              fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
            }
         catch(Exception e){ }
```

I want to add a log in catch block so that any kind of exception can be printed in my log file. Kindly help ... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File("c:\\className").mkdir();
```

`mkDir` returns `boolean` you need the correction as

```
File file = new File("c:\\classname");
file.mkdir();
```

Comment: Not working. Compilation succeeded but i did not get the folder in c drive? What went wrong here...The exact code is here           try{
  File file=new File("C:\\className");
  file.mkdir();
    fh = new FileHandler("C:\\className\\Localizerapplet.log");   
         logger.addHandler(fh); 
  logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
  SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
              fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
            }
      catch(Exception e){ }

Comment: check with System.out.println(file.mkdir()); if it returns false, may be you dont have permission on c drive. try it on any other drive

Comment: in second attempt it created the directory... Thanks...Could you please help me with other 2 questions?

Comment: I want to name my log file depending upon no: of attempt to run my application. I found some code when google for it,they used date and time for it and cose was quite confusing... And also i have given code in try block in my question.... I want to print all exception in catch block using looger... Thanks

Comment: you need to store variable persisatbly may be in properties file or somewhere else to count for attempt to run. then you can name the log file as ""C:\\className\\"+ getAttemptCount() +".log""

Comment: i found the way for naming logs on attempts. Please guide me to print all exception caught in catch block with logger. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get compilation error if you use

```
File file=new File("C:\\className").mkdir();
```

Because, mkdir() returns boolean type. So, this has to be in another statement like this -

```
   File file=new File("C:\\className");
   boolean created = file.mkdir();
```

For logging, you may use log4j. It's simple to use.

Comment: Thank you... Could you please guide me to name the different log file using Logging API,because this is used in my application.... and what about printing all types of exception that may occur in a single catch??